# DD4T Will Support for Region Based Page Design | Tridion Sites 9.6

Tags: dd4t-2, sites-9.6

We are Using DD4T .NET MVC Web Application as Backend Support for SDL Tridion.

1.Do we have any code samples for Region Based Page Design for DD4T Templating? All the Tridion Sites9.6 functionalities will Support DD4T?

2.in DD4T Website It showing "DD4T for .NET now supports the latest version of Tridion Sites: 9.5. To upgrade, just replace the reference to your current DD4T provider package with DD4T.Providers.Tridion9.5.CIL." How can we proceed for Tridion 9.6?

3.Below Packages are Using for Tridion 9.6. Any version upgrade required?

```
 <package id="DD4T.Caching.ApacheMQ" version="2.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
 <package id="DD4T.Core" version="2.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
 <package id="DD4T.Logging.Log4Net" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
 <package id="DD4T.Model" version="2.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
 <package id="DD4T.MVC5" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
 <package id="DD4T.Providers.Tridion9.1.CIL" version="2.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Comment: Note you'll always want to test, but in general, most of the independently developed libraries (should) use publicly supported API methods or calls. Going into an upgrade, you can find potential issues if any of the extension or customization code is using _deprecated_ parts of the API, since a future version may have "completed" the deprecation process by _dropping_ those specific methods or calls.

Refer to the documentation for platform support.

Comment: I wrapped the package references in a code block. They weren't visible in your first edit. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK - Yes, From **DD4T.Model 2.5** Supported for Regions in Tridion 9 and higher.

Refer to https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates

Before the introduction of page regions in Tridion 9, the concept of **'regions'** of component presentations on a page was commonly implemented using a metadata field called **'region'** on the metadata of the component template. In that case, the web application would group component presentations together based on this metadata field.

With **DD4T 2.5** you can now upgrade your CM to Tridion 9.0+ and start using regions, without having to change your web application. All you need to do is add the new template building block '**Convert regions to CT metadata**' to your page templates. It will put a metadata field called region in each of the component templates, and put the name of the region in it.

Tridion Sites CIL libraries are backward and forward compatibility, with that DD4T provider package with **DD4T.Providers.Tridion9.5.CIL** should work in 9.6 also.